# Can there be a script imitating Windows 8 fast boot-up(shut down)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, script, windows-8-preview

In my understanding, booting up is just the reverse process used to turned off the pc last time. If you hibernated, you be booted up with reverse hibernation. If you did stand-by, you will get reverse. Recently, windows 8 team has uncovered their fast boot up process. Which is nothing but reverse process of fast shut down(log off then hibernate) they are doing IMHO. And if we can imitate that shutting down procedure, our windows pcs(xp or 7 or even vista) will boot up fast. So, can't there be a script to do that?

Log off then Hibernate?

Comment: Its very doubtful you will be able to do this.  Windows 8 was changed to support this.  You wouldn't be able to hibernate once you logged off a user's profile.

Answer (score 3):

The windows 8 fast boot includes starting up device drivers in parallel.  They're also hibernating the kernal itself aside from application data.   That's what makes it so fast.  I don't think you can script any of that stuff - it's all before Windows starts that the performance modifications have been done.

See [the relevant Windows 8 Build Team Blog entry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8) for more info.

Comment: Windows 7 had parallel driver initialization also.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loggin off to session 0 and then hibernating, your script needs to activate hibernate from session 0.

Logoff and hibernate is essentially what they are doing.

Technically it is possible, but I have no idea how to get a script to do it. Programming a service to do that is possible though.

Comment: Actually I have almost no idea about windows programming. I thought it might be done with a script. Given that's not possible, is it tough to program a service like that?

Comment: No idea. You should post a question on Stack Overflow , our sister site for questions like Win32 programming.